# get Row & Colum of a pixel in Image

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, pixel

I'm a beginner in Java and a geomatics student.I am using IntelliJ.

I have an array of pixel that creates a image with BufferedImage (and it works well).

```
private byte[] pixels;
private int totBytes;
totBytes = numDataBytesOfAChannelPing * frequencyList.get( selectFrequency ).getSize();
pixels = new byte[totBytes];
BufferedImage image1 = createBufferedImage( pixels, totBytes, numChans, bytesPerSample, width, height );
```

I would like to have in a multidimensionnal array the coordinates like row and column of each pixel, I don't know how to do it. I try :

EDIT :

```
int w = 0, h = 0;
int[][] tableauMulti = new int[w][h];
for ( byte pixelSanscCoordonnees : pixels )
{
    int i = pixels[0];
    int j = pixels[0];
    tableauMulti = new int [i][j];
}
```

I try, but it doesn't work well. With this all pixels of the image (129 000 000 pixels)  are use in the same time in the foreach loop..I don't know how to construct my foreach loop

Thank you

Comment: to start with, 1 byte is not normally equal to 1 pixel.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I have to admit, I don't know really how to construct my foreach loop

Comment: You have a `BufferedImage` object so why not use it? Look at [`getData()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getData()) for example, which will give you a `Raster` object you can manipulate pixel by pixel.

Comment: @dcsohl I have an array of the pixel use in the bufferedImage, I think the easiest way is to recover the data from the array, no?

Comment: The result of my code edit is : pixels : (15, -15, 90, -15, -112, -13 (...) + 129581174 more)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [BufferedImage.getRGB(int x, int y)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB(int,%20int)).  You can also get many pixels at once with [BufferedImage.getRGB(int startX, int startY, int w, int h, int[] rgbArray, int offset, int scansize)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int[],%20int,%20int)).

With this you won't actually have to create/store the array yourself, you can just get the info straight from the BufferedImage.

Java2s has some great tutorials.  [Here's one](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/GettingandSettingPixelsinaBufferedImage.htm) for getting/setting pixels in a BufferedImage.

Comment: I have to stock data in a multidimensionnak array, because I will then make calculations on each pixel's value...help me !

Comment: Can you clarify what the goal is?  For example, are you using the multidimensional array so that you can get the pixel value at a certain row/column?  i.e. pixelOfInterest = tableauMulti[3][5]; to get the pixel in row 3, col 5?  And then what will you then do with that data?   More info will be helpful to come up with the best solution!